# Convert elements of a list in tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have the following list:

```
list_c = ['42.2529, -73.7910', '42.079846, -76.499364', '42.361824, -73.597979', '42.035959, -73.580146']
```

I'd like to convert to this:

```
list_c2 =  [(42.2529, -73.7910),(42.079846, -76.499364),(42.361824, -73.597979),(42.035959, -73.580146)]
```

The code am trying is:

```
list_c2 = [(list_c[i]) for i in range(0, len(list_c))]
print("list_c2 =", list_c)
```

Unfortunately, the result is exactly the same as `list_c`

Comment: What do you want to happen if your original list has an odd number of elements?

Comment: i have a slight correction to make to my question: the desired result actually is:

list_c2 = [(42.2529, -73.7910),(42.079846, -76.499364),(42.361824, -73.597979),(42.035959, -73.580146)]

i.e., just tuples of numbers (without the ' ' marks)!

and it doesn't matter how many elements are in the original list, the desired result should always have the same # of elements as the original list.

also, i've searched the previous answers, but unfortunately couldn't find any answer to this specific one.  the difference i believe is the elements of the original list are already in pairs.

Comment: In that case, your list to floats before running the linked functions: `list_c = [float(x) for x in list_c]`

Comment: that doesn't work. am getting an error ... "Could not convert string to float: '42.2529, -73.7910'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I misread you list initially.  To convert this into pairs of floats, you'll need to `split` each string on its comma and then make each element a `float`, then pack them in a tuple:

```
list_c2 = [tuple(float(item) for item in s.split(',')) for s in list_c]
# [(42.2529, -73.791), (42.079846, -76.499364), (42.361824, -73.597979), (42.035959, -73.580146)]
```